# multiple joins with criteria in one of them

Tags: mysql, join

thanks for answering.

Using mysql 5.6, I have 2 tables.

### Fund

- Code
- Name
- etc.

### Policy

- Code
- Value
- DOD  (date of death)
- etc

I'm trying to get output of

- Name
- sum of values for that code
- count of values for that code
- sum of values for that code where dod is null
- count of values for that code where dod is null

Here's the sql that doesn't quite work:

```
Select fund.code, value, ActValue, count, actcount
from fund
join(select code, sum(value)as value, count(code) as count from policy group by code) policy
join(select code, sum(value)as ActValue, count(code) as Actcount from policy where DOD is null group by code ) active
on fund.code = policy.code and fund.code = active.code
```

This gives me an empty result. If I remove the where... in the second join I get data, but of course it just duplicates the policy totals.  How do I go about adding a criteria to the 2nd join only?

Thanks,
Mike.

edit: Thanks - Can't call both the answer even though you both had it right. Its working in my test environment now so I presume it'll work in the live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select fund.code, value, ActValue, count, actcount
    from fund 
    left join (select code, sum(value)as value, count(code) as count from policy group by code) policy on fund.code=policy.code
    left join (select code, sum(value)as ActValue, count(code) as Actcount from policy where DOD is null group by code )on fund.code=active.code
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand problem right, you need to go with:

```
select fund.code, IFNULL(policy.value, 0), IFNULL(active.ActValue, 0), IFNULL(policy.count, 0), IFNULL(active.actcount, 0)
from fund
left outer join
(
    select code, sum(value) as value, count(code) as count from policy group by code
) policy
on (fund.code = policy.code)
left outer join
(
    select code, sum(value) as ActValue, count(code) as Actcount from policy where DOD is null group by code
) active
on (fund.code = active.code)
```